# Remove-AzureAdUserExtension actual result

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

In Azure AAD, I want to use Powershell to clear the value for a user's extension attribute named "employeeId". When I try to **Set-AzureAdUserExtension** to $null or "", it gives a binding error. Will **Remove-AzureAdUserExtension** do this? All the help files, docs and internet searches about this command say that it "Removes a user extension from Azure Active Directory".  I'm *pretty sure* that means it will clear the attribute value for one user, as I want. But I'm *afraid* it might try to remove the user extension attribute from the schema, which is absolutely what I don't want.

Please help me confirm this command's effect before I blow up my customer's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just remove the attribute value for one user, rather than remove the user extension attribute from the schema, feel free to use it.

Test sample:

```
Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId <user-object-id>
Remove-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId <user-object-id> -ExtensionName employeeId
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the extra-clear answer, Joy!  All the docs I found only had that one ambiguous statement as explanation, nothing more. Great help.